# Downcast any to a more specific type in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I make a protocol:

```
protocol TestProtocol {
    func test() -> Int
}
```

and I extend the Int and Optional to conform the protocol:

```
extension Int: TestProtocol {
    func test() -> Int {
        return 1
    }
}

extension Optional where Wrapped: TestProtocol {
    func test() -> Int {
        switch self {
        case let value?:
            return value.test()
        default:
            return 0
        }
    }
}
```

I may also extend String, Double and other types conform this protocol.

If I give the specific type of variable, it works ok:

```
let fff: Int? = 2
print(fff.test())
```

But if the variable type is any:

```
let kkk: Any = fff
print(kkk.test())
```

How to check kkk's true type conforming protocol TestProtocol and get the result.

Comment: In this example, `Optional` does not conform to `TestProtocol`. When `Optional` wraps something that conforms, it has a `test()` method, but that is not sufficient for `Optional` itself to conform. There is no conditional conformance in Swift. You can't say "Array are Equatable if their elements are Equatable." See https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/GenericsManifesto.md#conditional-conformances- for more.

Comment: Thank you! You solved my problem!

Answer (score 2):

Use optional binding:

```
let kkk: Any = 42   // Actually an Int
if let k = kkk as? TestProtocol {
    print(k.test())
} else {
    print("kkk does not conform to TestProtocol")
}
```